# disable beep/bell notification from irssi when terminal in focus?

Tags: osx, irssi, bell

In `irssi`, it is easy to enable bells on notifications (mentions, or direct messages) with the following command:

`/SET beep_msg_level MSGS HILIGHT DCCMSGS`

However; this does just that. It sends beeps on highlights, and private messages — regardless of terminal state. Is there a way to continue to receive beeps, but only if the terminal window is not in focus? It does not make much sense to receive beeps in a private chat if you're already actively chatting.

I am using Bash on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy for an application running in a terminal to know if the terminal is in focus or not. The terminal itself can help you out though.

Here are your options with macOS terminals:

- Terminal.app

  In Profiles → Advanced → Bell you can turn off the audible bell, but turn on "Bounce app icon when in background".
- iTerm2

  Similarly to Terminal.app, in Profiles → Terminal → Notifications you can silence the bell and turn on notification center alerts.

If you use tmux you can also change the behavior in your tmux settings. The global option `bell-action` controls what happens when a bell rings in one of your windows<sup>1</sup>. By default it is set to `any` which means that bells will always ring. You can change it to only ring for windows other than the current window with

```
set -g bell-action other
```